# O que a cláusula object define em Scala?

Tags: scala

Estudando alguns projetos, encontrei um código intrigante, onde além da cláusula `class` que define um objeto, já conhecida do Java, há a cláusula `object`, desconhecida para mim até então.

```
object Counter {
  val InitialValue = 10000000L; // (ten million)
  val CounterKey = "counter"
}

@Singleton
class Counter @Inject()(
  client: JedisClient) {

  def next: Long = {
    val current: Long = Option(client.get(CounterKey)) match {
      case Some(value) =>
        value.toLong
      case None =>
        InitialValue
    }
    val nextValue = current + 1
    client.set(CounterKey, nextValue.toString)
    nextValue
  }
}
```

O que o `object Counter` define neste caso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A declaração `object` introduz o objeto chamado singleton, que é uma classe que possuirá apenas uma única instância. A declaração acima constrói tanto a classe chamada Counter quanto sua instância, também chamada de Counter. Esta instância é criada sob demanda, no momento do seu primeiro uso.

#### Exemplo com método `main`:

```
object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

Neste exemplo é possível perceber que o código do método main não é declarado
como `static` aqui. Isso ocorre por que membros estáticos (métodos ou campos)
não existem em Scala. Ao invés de usar métodos estáticos, o programador Scala
declara esses membros como objetos singleton.

#### O que o object Counter define?

Ele define duas variáveis `InitialValue` e `CounterKey` que são estáticas.